# Can't create subfolder of INBOX squirrelmail

Tags: mail

That is my problem, that I can't createsubfolder of INBOX in squirrelmail (1.4.23).
Here is the picture.

[image]

I can't choose INBOX from the rolling down menu. I want to create there a subfolder like Trash. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know. I have a howto from my teacher. He can create subfolder into INBOX. (but he uses 1.4.21)

Comment: @Rinzwind I think the Squirrelmail server is running on Ubuntu (it is certainly not a Windows program). And yes, it is possible to create subfolders in Squirrelmail.

Comment: But why can't I vcreate it? Can you tell me jos? *.*

Comment: It is probably a permissions issue. Look in the Apache log files (/var/log/apache2/error.log).

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Make folders from server? Drafts, Sent, Trash is automatically generated. I don't have an idea why does this program this with me. It's annoying, because my teacher can create into INBOX. (but he uses 1.4.21, I use 1.4.23)

Comment: @Rinzwind OK, you go for it :-)

Comment: I don't believe it!!!!!! It just become good itself!!! I didn't setup anything. Here is the picture. http://cubeupload.com/im/O60bcJ.png   But there is an error with apache. :)

Comment: @icebolt gratz. Please add it in as an answer and accept it ;)

Comment: How can I add it as an answer?

Comment: Something is still wrong: `the requested URL left_main.php was not found`. It should be there though, it creates the blue left column, which was there in the earlier screenshot.

Comment: I refreshed and there is now. :)